# How to compare the data entered from the program and the data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to compare the data entered from the program with the data in MongoDB. How can I do it?

```
import pymongo
from getpass import getpass

baglanti = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:secure@denemeler.s4ufh.mongodb.net/Bankamatik?authSource=admin&w=majority&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&retryWrites=true&ssl=true")
bankamatik = baglanti["Bankamatik"]
hesap = bankamatik["BankaHesapBilgileri"]

def kayitOl():
    kullaniciadi = input("Kayıt bölümüne hoş geldiniz. \nKullanıcı adı: ")
    sifre = getpass("Şifre(gizli): ")

    hesap.insert({"kullaniciadi": kullaniciadi, "sifre": sifre, "bakiye": 1000})

    print("Kayıt başarıyla oluşturulmuştur.")

print("Hoş geldiniz.")
girismenu = int(input("Hoş geldiniz. Giriş yapmak isterseniz 1, hesabınız yok ve kayıt olmak isterseniz 2 yazınız."))
if girismenu == 2:
    kayitOl()

if girismenu == 1:
    print("Giriş yapma kısmındasınız. Lütfen bilgilerinizi girin.")
    kullaniciadi = input("Kullanıcı adı: ")
    sifre = getpass("Şifre(gizli): ")

    arama = hesap.find().sort("kullaniciadi")

    for x in arama:
        print(x["kullaniciadi"])
```

I stayed here and couldn't continue.

Example:

Database: kullaniciadi: "emro", sifre: 33
Program input: kullaniciadi: "emro", sifre: 33

Login successful.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the filter parameters into `find()` or `find_one()`

e.g.

```
user_input = input("Input")
records = hesap.find({"field": user_input})
```

or

```
user_input = input("Input")
record = hesap.find_one({"field": user_input})
```

Comment: So how can I query whether this data is correct? with if.

Comment: if you use `find_one` you can check `if record is not None:` to see if there is a match.